# Using GitPython in Azure DevOps pipelines causes 'git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command

Tags: git, azure-devops, gitpython, azure-devops-pipelines, git-credential-manager

When we use GitPython in Azure DevOps and try to push to a repository, the following message occurs (same repository as cloned by the pipeline):

```
  stderr: 'git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Infrastructure: GitHub, Windows build machine (latest)

Since our working-directory is the currently cloned repository, we initialize the repository like this:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo('.')
# Do some stuff
repo.git.execute('git add --all -- ":!build-infrastructure"')
repo.git.execute(f'git commit -m "{generic_commit_message}"')
repo.git.execute('git push')
```

So pushing the changes should work with the same credentials, as Azure DevOps used for pulling. Am I missing something?

**SOLUTION**

The solution is to override the `checkout` step in the pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
    persistCredentials: true
```

Comment: side note : you should be able to call git subcomannds as though they were methods of the `repo.git` object ([link to docs](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly)) e.g : `repo.git.add('--all', '--', ':!build-infrastructure')`, `repo.git.commit('-m', generic_commit_message)`,  `repo.git.push()`, etc ...

Comment: @LeGEC good point, this is much more straight forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The solution is to override the checkout step in the pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
    persistCredentials: true
```

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I will do this, it's just possible tomorrow.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Were there any changes in behavior? Last week it still worked without `checkout ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Check what url is used for the remote is registered : `repo.git.remote('-v')`

It could be that the url is one that wouldn't need credentials when pulling.

---

I, for one, don't know how the container (or process or whatever) that is started by Azure DevOps is created ; it could well be that the setup is done with one account, then the commands are executed with a different one (or within a container, or ... )

Check how the config is set up : `repo.git.config('-l')`, if target executable is available from the `$PATH` ...

---

You may need to add some step in the setup part of your pipeline (e.g: install said credential manager).

Comment: thanks for you help, the solution was to allow connection persistence in the checkout-step.